# 1988 AIME Problems/Problem 15. Problem related to ordering of letters and typings...

Tags: combinatorics

**1988 AIME Problems/Problem 15**

**Problem:**
In an office at various times during the day, the boss gives the secretary a letter to type, each time putting the letter on top of the pile in the secretary's in-box. When there is time, the secretary takes the top letter off the pile and types it. There are nine letters to be typed during the day, and the boss delivers them in the order $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

While leaving for lunch, the secretary tells a colleague that letter $8$ has already been typed, but says nothing else about the morning's typing. The colleague wonders which of the nine letters remain to be typed after lunch and in what order they will be typed. Based upon the above information, how many such after-lunch typing orders are possible? (That there are no letters left to be typed is one of the possibilities.)

I am unable to think of a proper way to frame the answer. Could someone kindly provide a **simple** answer, with a lot of explanation. Binomial coefficient-related methods or, if possible, a generating function approach would really be helpful and instructive. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know $8$ has already been typed, so from $1$ to $7$ have been added to the pile at some point. And about $9$ you don't know if it has been added to the pile or not.
Given a subset $P$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, if the number of elements in $P$ is $p$, you can add the $9$ before typing the first element of the subset, before typing the second element of the subset, ..., before typing the last element of the subset, after typing the last element of the subset or you can have the $9$ been added already, what gives us $p+2$ different possibilities for each subset $P$ . So for a subset $P$ of length $p$, there are $p+2$ different typing orders. If you multiply this for the number of ways you can arrange $p$ elements of a set of length $7$, and do this for all $p\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ you get the answer:
$$ \sum_{p=0}^7{7 \choose p}(p+2)=704$$

Comment: I'm sorry for disturbing you but could you clarify this: So, basically you get (p+1) from P ∪ {9} and the other +1 from the case wherein 9 is absent? So, finally, we get (p+2)? But thanks for the answer anyway! Really appreciated.

Comment: Am I right that the number of typing orders *from the start of the day* is just $9!$ ?

Comment: I have edited it, I am not good at explaining these things, but if you don't get it, I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: @Vasu090 No, for example you cannot type the $6$, then the $4$ and then the $5$.

Comment: So, what is the answer to that question? Seems quite puzzling. :)

Comment: Thanks, so much @Alfredo! You're an angel! Really, man, much obliged!